# Getting value from specific cell in an html table is not working using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get row data from a table so I can use it in a modal. Below is my code for Views.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#acctInfo").DataTable();
        $(".td_0").hide();
    });
</script>

<!-- Page Title
   ============================================= -->
<section id="page-title">

    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1>View Accounts</h1>
    </div>
</section><!-- #page-title end -->


<section id="content">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="acctInfo">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td_0">Account Id</th>
                    <th>Employee Id</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Business Name</th>
                    <th>Account Type</th>
                    <th></th>
                    @*<th></th>*@
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var i in Model.AccountsViews)
                {
                    <tr id="rowx">
                        <td > @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.AcctId)</td>
                        <td > @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.EmployeeId)</td>
                        <td > @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.FirstName)</td>
                        <td > @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.MiddleName)</td>
                        <td > @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.LastName)</td>
                        <td > @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.BusinessName)</td>
                        <td > @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.AccountType)</td>
                        @*<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="lnkEdit btn btn-success form-control">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="lnkDelete btn btn-danger form-control">Delete</a></td>*@
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="OpenSelected()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div id="divEdit" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidId"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee Id</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtEmployeeId" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Middle Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtMiddleName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtLastName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Business Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtBusinessName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        @*<tr>
            <td>Account Type</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(o => )
            </td>
        </tr>*@
    </table>
</div>

<script>

    function OpenSelected() {

        var a = $('.trSelected td').eq(4).text();
        alert(a);
    }
</script>
```

With that code, I am able to invoke the alert method with the following code:

```
<script>

        function OpenSelected() {

            var a = $('.trSelected td').eq(4).text();
            alert(a);
        }
    </script>
```

but it has no value of the cell that I need. It only has "localhost/1234 Says: " the alert has no value. I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: There are no elements that have `class="trSelected"`. Is there another part of your code that adds such a class?

Comment: I just copied it from one of the answers here is stack.

Comment: there are no class exists in your html `trSelected ` and also the each `tr ` element having only max two `td` element here. So please write your script accordingly

Comment: @Ibanez1408 - did you tried after copying it?

Comment: Check you selector. It should be the problem

Comment: `$(inputs).parent('td').closest('tr').find('td').eq(4).text();`    
 inline function call should be `onclick="OpenSelected(this)"` function should be   `function OpenSelected(inputs) { .. }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to following code... .closset would give you the selected row and than you find columns value on the base of indexes.

```
           <script>
                $('.btn-success').click(function () {
                    var a = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
                    var b = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();
                    alert(a);
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: User need to pass context of clicked element. `this` won't work here

Comment: Its corrected now and working fine. Ibanez1408 give a try

Comment: It is working but you need to click multiple times to close the alert. Example, on the first button click, the value comes out but the alert executes twice. Then I click another button and the alert comes out with value but I have to press thrice to close the alert. Then I click another button, the alert comes out with correct value but, I have to click 4 times to close the alert button.... A little more help please...

Comment: @lbanez You must have multiple buttons with the same class name.... try to give this button a unique class

I mean this class '.btn-success' add another class in your edit button i.e. 'editRecorClass' somthing like this and than try it as a selector

Comment: onclick="OpenSelected()"

Remove this from your html as we are using class as a selector and you don't need it

Comment: Thank you muhammed.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector at this context

You should use `.text()` instead to retrieve its text content,

```
var t = $('#table');
var val1 = $(t).find('tr:eq(2) td:eq(4)').text();
alert(val1);
```

Or do,

```
alert($('#table tr:eq(2) td:eq(4)').text());
```

### [DEMO](https://output.jsbin.com/cilibotage)

Comment: I need to get the first cell of the row where my button is. This only gets the particular row and cell no matter what row button I click. Can you revise the code to make it work for my situation. Thank you.